# How do I calculate the type and size of battery to use for this solar-powered USB charger?

Tags: battery-charging, battery-operated, solar-energy, diy, time-constant

I've been out of the electrical mathematics for a while and want to see what battery I need to do this.

1. 5 V USB output, 5 V DC solar power panel (I do have two I could use together, assuming the chief connections/battery)
2. 5 V 2 A power draw.

What battery to buy to power two, after fully charged, and connected to the small solar panel? Also possibly a timer between the battery and what's being powered (example entry way door light on overnight (6-8 hrs of battery use before the solar can take over powering/charging said battery. All USB connections (not sure there's a timer switch USB to USB. I'd be happy to make and mass-produce it if there isn't one, but yes, solar panel, USB, what needs to be powered USB, so battery needs USB coming in and out the door. Also, possibly expandable to handle two of the solar panels and two power draws? Probably easier to use separate batteries with each panel to power said 'light'?

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not a forum. Your question should be succinct and get to the point. Adding the extra detail of your personal situation is not necessary (in fact, since it detracts from the question, it actually _slows_ the process of getting you an answer). Note the edits I've made to your question. Feel free to add technical details if necessary.

Comment: Is it correct to summarize that; 1) You have a solar panel which has some electronics already associated with it to output 5 volts via a USB receptacle? 2) You have some sort of load (a light in your example) that requires 2 A at 5 V? 3) You are wanting to determine the correct battery size to operate the load for 6-8 hours? 4) That you might  want to use two of these and are wondering how they may or may not be combined?

Comment: Sounds like a USB power bank with an added timer.

Comment: @JYelton 1)yes. 2) yes, also what size solar panel for 4a at 10V possibly? 3)yes, 4-6 hrs dedicated battery use a day, battery charged/load powered simultaneously by the solar during daylight hours utilizing a solar converter? 4) yes, how to properly combine, scale the solar system.      Usb power bank could work with a timer, but isn't a converter necessary to both charge the battery and power the load at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

### Interpreting the Question

Based on your added comments, I'll try to re-state your question here:

*You want to power a light for 6-8 hours overnight from a battery which is charged via solar panel. The light is 10 watts (5 V at 2 A) and you'd like to determine the size of battery (and solar panel) needed to enable this to work.*

Your original question and comments are bringing in some additional confusing elements (such as USB, switches, timers, etc.) which aren't really part of the primary question, which is: **How do I calculate the type and size of battery to use for this solar-powered USB charger?**

### To USB or Not to USB

While it may be the case that whatever prototype or product you've got so far may utilize USB as its output/input, since it is a common and popular standard, you don't necessarily need to retain USB (or its associated voltage) if you intend to design and build your own product. This may be especially important if the solar panel and light you are using aren't actually operating at 5 V to begin with (they're probably not), which means there are some voltage step-down/up operations happening which add inefficiency.

For example, the light, as we've established, requires 2 amperes at 5 volts. But maybe your light is an LED fixture which uses a constant-current regulator to provide the LEDs a fixed current and only needs some minimum voltage across them. That could vary from a couple of volts to tens of volts depending on how the LEDs are connected. All I am saying here is that instead of converting the voltage from the panel to a suitable battery charge voltage, and from the battery voltage to 5 V as a USB interconnect, then again to some other voltage to power the LEDs, you could potentially select a different voltage that is more efficient. I'm not saying that 5 V isn't a valid choice, but keep in mind that you don't necessarily have to use USB and 5 V unless that is part of your design requirement.

Similarly, your solar panel has some associated circuitry that is providing 5 V output, but again, you could select something else if desired. As a quick example, let's say you settled on a battery topology that used two Lithium-based cells in series. If each cell is 3.7 volts, the battery would be 7.4 volts, and require a charging voltage slightly higher. This is just an example, again, in case USB isn't a requirement.

### Light (Load) and Battery

The light requires 10 W, which for 8 hours of continuous operation is 80 watt-hours (\$8h\times10W\$). Let's use the same battery from the above example, 7.4 volt Li-ion. You would thus need a battery with at least ~10.8 amp-hour (Ah) capacity (\$80 Wh/7.4 V\$). Here is [an example](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/5035/5035_10050mAh_3.7V_A1____20210511.pdf) of a 3.7 volt battery that uses three cells in parallel and is rated for 10 Ah. You'd connect two of these in series to achieve 7.4 volts and have a total 10 Ah capacity. (To elaborate in case you are wondering why the second battery is needed: If you only used one of these, your voltage would be 3.7 volts with 10 Ah capacity. Converting it to whatever voltage the light needs, whether that's 5 V or something else, the math is \$3.7V\times10Ah=37Wh\$ which is just under half of the required 80 Wh.) This is just back-of-the-envelope stuff, because you have to account for inefficiencies and the fact that a battery won't necessarily provide its full capacity depending on the type of load it is rated for. *Of course, double the load value if, per your question, there are two lights. This detail wasn't very clear.*

### Solar Panel

Photovoltaic cells produce about 0.5 to 0.6 volts each, so different panels produce different voltages based on how all of their cells are connected. Generally it is desirable for maximum power to connect many cells in series for higher voltages and then connect panels or arrays of cells in parallel as needed once a given voltage for the design is achieved. Small panels I work with typically provide 15 to 20 volts in full sun.

That said, you will find solar panels generally provide a rating in watts (at peak insolation) so you can think about this logically: If the load at night is using 80 watt hours, then your solar panel needs to at least exceed that value during the day. Sunlight coverage will vary depending on where the unit is installed, so you must factor that in. If you get 8 hours of sunlight, a 10 watt panel will barely suffice. If you can only count on 4 hours of sunlight, a 20 watt panel would be better. Clouds and storms, greater latitudes, etc. will all negatively affect performance, so you have to add more capacity.

### Putting It Together

Once the basic components discussed above are selected, connecting them into a coherent system is next. Components involved might include battery charge controllers, solar charge controllers (also called maximum power-point tracking (MPPT) controllers, microcontrollers, switching (buck/boost) voltage regulators, photocell, etc. All of this depends on what you are trying to do. Is the final product autonomous? Does it require user interaction? Is there a user interface? Is it meant to power only the light, or does it also need to provide some sort of USB connectivity? Are there size constraints? Are the panel and light in separate locations or within one enclosure? Does it turn on and off at specific times or just use a photo sensor? Is this meant to be a minimum-cost product, or something fancier? These are just a variety of questions whose answers can completely change how someone would answer you.

I wasn't able to really tell from your question if you are trying to assemble something using off-the-shelf products, or design something from the circuit board up. Since you mention "mass production" I assume the latter. Designing and manufacturing a product is obviously a large endeavor, and there is simply no way to address all of the concerns in a single question on this site.

I'll leave it here. If you have *specific* questions about electrical engineering aspects of your project, you're encouraged to ask them as new questions.

Comment: Thank you for that. I wasn't sure if I finished editing my followup before posting. Appreciate the through rely. Will ask or update as I go. Trying a little of both, building from scratch /DIY component parts as the answer to a lot of your questions are yes. Timer needed not photo sensor, app integration is end goal, but i know a lot of what I want to do is already out there in some capacity, I just need to put the puzzle together (though I'm really looking forward to the math and the assembly). Minimal design 1st then add until I can't, then refine.